# Promises in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor, es6-promise

I'm making an Async call on the server side, through `Meteor.methods`.

I would like my client to await for the async response before attempting to run any further logic.

I need help understanding how to leverage Async/Promises with remote HTTP requests.

Currently, I have a very simple event setup:

```
  'click #getOrders': function() {
    Meteor.call('getOrders', function(err, data) {
      if (!err) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  }
```

Which then calls:

```
var shopifyAPI = Meteor.npmRequire('shopify-node-api');
var Shopify = new shopifyAPI({
  shop: 'xxxxx.myshopify.com', 
  shopify_api_key: 'xxxxxx', 
  access_token: 'xxxxx' 
});

Meteor.methods({
  'getOrders': function() {

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      Shopify.get('/admin/orders/count.json', function(err, res) {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(res);
      });
    });

    promise.then(function(data) {
      return data;
    })

  }
})
```

When I click my event handler, I can see my server logs are correctly receiving data. Adding a `console.log` under `promise.then` confirms that the promise code is working.

However, my client side `console.log` is always undefined, due to it returning a result before my async response has come back. How can I handle this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the promise.

```
return promise;
```

After returning, on the client side call:

```
data.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Returning the promise is all I was missing.